# App no longer displaying in Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-center

I need to know whether Cool Retro Term (or cool-retro-term) is showing up for other people in the Ubuntu Software application manager.  Could somebody do a quick search and tell me whether it's showing up for you?

I downloaded this terminal emulator onto my machine, but now I'm not able to find it in the application manager, and I'm wondering if it's something I did or if the author took it down.

Comment: It is available as a snap: `sudo snap install cool-retro-term`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  But I also saw it and originally downloaded it from the Ubuntu Software manager that comes pre-installed on Ubuntu 18.04.3, but I don't see it there anymore when I search.  Do you?

Comment: No and `apt policy cool-retro*` doesn't turn up anything either. So it's no longer there.

Comment: Weird.  I guess I was lucky enough to get it while it was still up.  Great app.  My terminal looks like one of the terminals you hack from the Fallout franchise.

It's still there on Github: https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term
I wonder why the author took it down.

Answer (score 0):

`cool-retro-term` is still available as a snap:

```
~$ snap find cool-retro-term
Name             Version  Publisher  Notes    Summary
cool-retro-term  1.1.1    flscogna   classic  cool-retro-term is a terminal emulator.
```

and can be installed with

```
snap install cool-retro-term
```

It's also available in `gnome-software`:

[image]

You need to have `gnome-software-plugin-snap` installed in your system to handle snap-applications with `gnome-software` though.

Comment: I installed that plugin, restarted gnome-software, and now I can see it again.  Weird.  Thanks for your help!